# Javascript - Latest date and highest priority

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I identify a priority element that has the latest date and the highest priority setting.

_ In this same I am building an isotope application
http://jsfiddle.net/CXqM2/178/

the key here - is after updating the data. I want to identify/select the element that is a) the latest date notification - so most recent - AND - has the lowest notification id associated to it.

I've got li elements with data attributes - which look as follows

```
<li class="isotope-item" data-user-notification-id="3" data-user-notification-date="24/03/2014 12:00:10">
test
</li>
```

- stash the dates and notification ids from the dom
- sort by the latest date
- then loop through this until I find the lowest number?

here is my key for the notification id

```
0 - user messaged
1 - user viewed your profile
2 - user just joined
3 - user come online
```

Comment: I would handle this on the database level. I is not a good idea to mix UI and application logic.

Comment: here is the latest code in full - http://jsfiddle.net/CXqM2/179/ - here is a cut down version - which has an existing list - and isotope handling as standard - http://jsfiddle.net/CXqM2/180/

Comment: I understand - maybe you are right about that. I am building the UI component here first. I will need to revisit and build the server side logic for the json format. Maybe - just set a data-attribute having highest priority - and then I could clean up the dom without having to add the various data-attributes to handle the logic

Comment: Pio - in reference to the logic in general - what would be the best way of handling it. - Order the data via date first - then identify the lowest notification id first? or order it via notificataion id - lowest to highest and return the earliest date -

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/CXqM2/184/ - ok I've updated it - so it just selects the highest priority - the json is simpler, the frontend logic lifted - how would you go about though developing the backend logic for this - Pio over to you

Comment: In my opinion it all depends on your data. You don't need to sort both. Sort the sorter and get the `min` or `max` from the other. Not that the fastest (comparison based) sorting algorithms take `O(nlogn)` time, while getting the maximum is only `O(n)`

Comment: Also the good part of your server side approach is that you can index your database entries so in case you have large data sets it's significantly faster while if you need the entries only for this specific variable then you can just query it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would agree with Pio from the comments, if you can sort this in the database, do so. However if you really need to sort in javascript. Use the sort method.

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/9GUQ3/3/

```
var stuff = $('ul li').sort(function (a, b)
     {
         var dateA = $(a).attr('data-user-notification-date').split(' ')[0];
         var dateB = $(b).attr('data-user-notification-date').split(' ')[0];
         var priA = $(a).attr('data-user-notification-id');
         var priB = $(b).attr('data-user-notification-id');
         var dString = dateA.split(' ')[0];
         var dA = new Date();

         dA.setYear(dString.split('/')[2]);
         dA.setMonth(parseInt(dString.split('/')[1])-1);
         dA.setDate(dString.split('/')[0]);
         dA.setHours(0);
         dA.setMinutes(0);
         dA.setMilliseconds(0);
         dA.setSeconds(0);

         var dString = dateB.split(' ')[0];
         var dB = new Date();

         dB.setYear(dString.split('/')[2]);
         dB.setMonth(parseInt(dString.split('/')[1])-1);
         dB.setDate(dString.split('/')[0]);
         dB.setHours(0);
         dB.setMinutes(0);
         dB.setMilliseconds(0);
         dB.setSeconds(0);

         if(dA.toUTCString() == dB.toUTCString())
         {
             return parseInt(priA) > parseInt(priB) ? 1 : -1;
         } else {
             return dA <= dB ? 1 : -1;
         }
     });
    $('ul').html(stuff);
```

As a note this does nto take into account Hours, Minutes, Seconds or Milliseconds to better demonstrate that it works.

Comment: You may need to change the dX.setHours(0) and the subsequent methods to include the hours, minutes, and seconds if you so desire. Was just a little cumbersome in my example.

Comment: Would this ensure that 0 - is the highest priority? Along the date - idea being - if the user is looking a profile page - and a person messages them - and its the very latest thing to occur in the data stream - that is higher priority then a person just loggin in etc..

Comment: This orders by date then your 'id'. It does not take into account Hours, Minutes, Seconds or Milliseconds in the code I provided. If two dates are the same, it will sort by the ID starting with the lowest.

Comment: Hello James, what if it did take into account, hours, minutes, seconds - has the example avoided to do so for a specific reason - does it work more efficiently in this manner?

Comment: I would be programming this logic - via Java spring - using mongodb objs. Is anyone here brave enough to put the backend server side logic into practice? I do agree with Pio - it could be best done on the server side - but would it be a similar logic to the one appended here?

Comment: Just to better illustrate that it works. Before asking for help here on stackoverflow you should spend time trying to implement it yourself. You will never learn if someone else does it for you. As well as the premise of StackOverflow is that you do your due dilligence before asking for help.

Comment: Sure - but I have not yet started working on the backend section of this code. I will provide examples/work - as and when I cater for this backend part of the problem. If someone has the answer or can provide logic/enhancement on this exact problem. I will ask regardless if I have taken it on board myself yet.